# DataBinding: ComboBox.Text not updating when SelectedValue changes?

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox, bindingsource, selectedvalue

I have a `ProbationComboBox` with the `SelectedValue` bound to a `RegistrationBindingSource`, and the `DisplayMember` bound to a `ProbationBindingSource`.

When I call `RegistrationBindingSource.ResetCurrentItem()`, the `SelectedValue` property is refreshed with the correct value from `RegistrationBindingSource.ProbationID()`, but the `Text` property isn't updated.

Here's how I setup data-binding on the ComboBox:

```
ProbationComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding( _
   "SelectedValue", Me.RegistrationBindingSource, "ProbationID", True))

ProbationComboBox.DataSource = Me.ProbationBindingSource
ProbationComboBox.DisplayMember = "probation"
ProbationComboBox.ValueMember = "id"
```

Until I can figure out the problem with my binding, I've using this as a temporary fix:

```
DataRow row = CType(ProbationBindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Row
ProbationComboBox.Text = CType(row, RootNamespace.DataSet.probationRow).probation
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with data binding to the `RegistrationBindingSource`, but with my data and procedures. Here's what was happening:

1. I would clear the `Text` property of all `ComboBox` controls before a record load.
2. `ProbationBindingSource.Current` got updated, either by data binding or by manually setting `ProbationComboBox.SelectedValue` property.
3. In most cases, students were not on probation, and the value of `ProbationBindingSource.Current` got updated with the same value as before. As a result, `ProbationBindingSource.Position` didn't change and the `Text` property wasn't updated.

My final solution checks if a given `SelectedValue` is going to be updated before clearing the `Text` property.

Answer (score 1):

What about calling ResetBindings?

The help files say that doing this "causes a control bound to the BindingSource to reread all the items in the list and refresh their displayed values."

Comment: I tried this, with no luck. I even tried passing True for the argument, to force the schema to be re-read, but it didn't help.